# GUI Java FX app is not responding after pressing button

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I ve been working on JAVA FX application which uploads certain file on remote computer and then executing mentioned file via cmd. It's working with all platforms Windows, Linux and Mac but I have one problem.

Problem: when file is bigger GUI totally crashes resulting in unable to click or do anything (App Not responding) eventhough file is uploaded and run via CMD after I check it.

I've been reading that JAVA FX is using single thread for GUI and all operations so basicly I need to create separate thread for GUI and separate thread for other code. I ve been trying to figure this out for pass 3 days and couldnt come up with solution. My program consists of more classes which depends on each other resulting to be harder to come up with solution. Will anybody be kind to help me with this problem?
Please bare in mind I m not a programmer this is kind of my hobby I know this programm does not fullfill coding standards.

Code:

Main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.IOException;


public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("GUI.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 600, 420);
        stage.setTitle("App name");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        Image icon = new Image("icon.png");
        stage.getIcons().add(icon);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Class Uploader:

```
import net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient;
import net.schmizz.sshj.transport.verification.PromiscuousVerifier;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Uploader {
    public String remoteHost;
    public String username;
    public String password;
    public String path;
    public String filename;

    public Uploader(String remoteHost,String username,String password, String path, String filename){
        this.remoteHost = remoteHost;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.path = path;
        this.filename = filename;
    }
    public SSHClient setupSshj() throws IOException {
        SSHClient client = new SSHClient();
        client.addHostKeyVerifier(new PromiscuousVerifier());
        client.connect(remoteHost);
        client.authPassword(username, password);
        return client;
    }

    public void whenUploadFileUsingSshj_thenSuccess(String osType) throws IOException {
        String localFilePath = "";
        String remoteDirPath = "";
        SSHClient sshClient = setupSshj();
        System.out.println("Connection established...");
        SFTPClient sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient();
        if (osType.equals("win")){
            remoteDirPath = "C:\\"+filename;
            localFilePath = path+filename;
        }
        else if (osType.equals("lin")) {
            remoteDirPath = "//tmp//" + filename;
            localFilePath = path+filename;
        }
        else{
            remoteDirPath = "Downloads//" + filename;
            localFilePath = path+filename;
        }

        sftpClient.put(localFilePath, remoteDirPath);
        System.out.println("File uploaded successfully...");
        sftpClient.close();
        sshClient.disconnect();
    }
}
```

class Cmdrunner:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import com.pastdev.jsch.DefaultSessionFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CommandRunner {
    public CommandRunner(String username, String hostname, String password, String cmd) throws JSchException, IOException {
        DefaultSessionFactory sessionFactory = new DefaultSessionFactory(username, hostname, 22);
        Map props = new HashMap<String, String>();
        props.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        sessionFactory.setConfig(props);
        sessionFactory.setPassword(password);

        com.pastdev.jsch.command.CommandRunner runner = new com.pastdev.jsch.command.CommandRunner(sessionFactory);
        com.pastdev.jsch.command.CommandRunner.ExecuteResult result = runner.execute(cmd);
        System.out.println("cmd successfully executed...");

        runner.close();
    }
}
```

class Controler:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Controller {
    String osType = "win";
    @FXML
    public TextField host_input;
    public TextField user_input;
    public TextField pass_input;
    public TextField path_input;
    public TextField file_name;
    //public Label state_id;


    @FXML
    public void winOs() { osType = "win";
        file_name.setText("File name");
    }
    public void linOs() {
        osType = "lin";
        file_name.setText("Filename");
    }
    public void macOs() { osType = "mac"; }
    public void upload() throws IOException, JSchException {
        //state_id.setText("");
        Uploader upload = new Uploader(host_input.getText(),user_input.getText(),pass_input.getText(),
                path_input.getText(), file_name.getText());
        upload.whenUploadFileUsingSshj_thenSuccess(osType);
        if (osType.equals("win")){
            new CommandRunner(user_input.getText(),host_input.getText(),pass_input.getText(),
                        String.format("C:\\%s --silent --accepteula",file_name.getText()));
            //state_id.setText("Installer uploaded and run successfully!");
        }
        if (osType.equals("lin")){
            new CommandRunner(user_input.getText(),host_input.getText(),pass_input.getText(),
                        "chmod 777 //tmp//"+file_name.getText());
            new CommandRunner(user_input.getText(),host_input.getText(),pass_input.getText(),
                        String.format("echo %s | sudo -S //tmp//%s", pass_input.getText(), file_name.getText()));
        }
        else {
            new CommandRunner(user_input.getText(),host_input.getText(),pass_input.getText(),
                        "chmod 777 Downloads//"+file_name.getText());
            new CommandRunner(user_input.getText(),host_input.getText(),pass_input.getText(),
                        "Downloads//"+file_name.getText());
        }
    }
    public void exit() {
        Platform.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this Web page? [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm)? I'm guessing that a large file takes a long time to upload and if you are performing the upload on the JavaFX application thread, then that thread cannot respond to user actions while the upload is running. Read the above linked Web page. It explains how to create a `Task` and run it on a separate thread so as to allow the JavaFX application thread to continue to respond to user actions while the `Task` is executing.

Comment: Just to note: You do not need to create a separate thread for the GUI. That thread (i.e. the _JavaFX Application Thread_) is created and managed automatically by the JavaFX framework. That said, you do need to create a separate/background thread for your long running tasks. And you need to make sure to implement proper communication between the FX thread and the background thread. The "Concurrency in JavaFX" article linked by Abra gives some good information.

Comment: Thank you guy for response I was finally able to achieve what I wanted it was tough battle. I created Task for upload as recommended by Abra. Been struggling with updating GUI during process but managed to get it working finally. Kleopatra I m sorry I triggered you with my question keep in mind not everybody is programming for more than decade and everybody has to start somewhere. I m aware of my lack of knowledge thats why I turned for help in this forum. Thank you again guys.